# Raspberry Pi 3 not receiving from Arduino Mega over GPIO UART

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi3, pyserial, uart

I'm trying to connect my Raspberry Pi 3 to an Arduino Mega 2560 over UART using the Rx and Tx pins (not USB cable). I went through all the steps to configure the Raspberry Pi to use the GPIO pins (https://spellfoundry.com/2016/05/29/configuring-gpio-serial-port-raspbian-jessie-including-pi-3/). For now, I'm just trying out the simplest code I can think of to make sure the connection is working (which it is not).

Arduino code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Start");

}

void loop() {
  Serial.write(".");
}
```

Raspberry Pi code:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/serial0', 9600)

while 1:
    x = ser.readline()
    print x
```

It's not giving me any errors or anything, but when I run the python code on the Raspberry Pi I get nothing. I'm using a logic level converter between the Pi and Arduino. Using a multimeter, I found that there is a signal going from the Arduino to the Pi, which is around 2.5V. Is this enough for the Pi? Could this be the problem? If so, what is causing it? I used 2 different Arduinos and I'm getting the same result from both.

I just don't understand what I'm doing wrong here and would really appreciate it if someone could help.